# Novel about a young vampire with a story spanning many centuries

Tags: story-identification, novel, vampire

At the end of the '80s or the start of the '90s, I was in a bookstore in London. There, I scanned through the fantasy corner and found a vampire novel that I somehow did not buy in the end. But I have been searching for that book ever since (I did not come back to the store again so the opportunity was lost).

Here are the details I can remember, which are unfortunately only a few. But maybe someone here has an idea:

- The story was about a rather young vampire, possibly a child.
- The story spanned many centuries.
- There was a scene where the vampire was giving a concert (so he must be a musician in the more recent past) where vampire hunters try to kill him. He jumps into the crowd and turns into some animal (I think a panther) and kills quite a few people.
- The book was rather thick, I would say more than 500 pages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds a bit like "Vampire Junction" by S. P. Somtow. I can't find a decent precis, but this is the most common one I can see. ". . . It's about rock music, about mass hysteria, about vampires, about horror . . . one comes out knowing, and caring, about a panoply of new friends and acquaintances, living and dead, and unalive".--Theodore Sturgeon, The Washington Post. [Some goodreads reviews](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/822044.Vampire_Junction?from_search=true&from_srp=true&qid=bwFOHCGjpR&rank=1) are better but I don't want to risk a spoiler.

Cover[image]

Comment: That sounds very familiar including the cover. I will check that out later but I have a good feeling :)

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure Ive found the paperback version I had in my hands, https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/37824049-vampire-junction. Thanks dude, that's wonderful. Now that I've read the reviews I'm not sure if I should read it, but out of principle I guess I will ^^

Comment: I checked out the copy at IA and read the first 100 pages. It is definitely the book. I have somehow mixed feelings since for my present self it reads as if the author was on drugs when he wrote it :)